# Angularjs - Json Emittted has Index number on sub object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I have a form that has three fixed questions, each question is followed by two drop down control for a user to select.

Since my number of  questions are fixed and will remain fixed , I am not using ng-repeat to render my questions.

In the end, I want my structure to be represented as

```
    Attendee
    -Name
    -Email
    -EventCollection
    ---Event1
    ----Event1Name
    ----IsAccepted
    ----TotalAdults
    ----TotalChildren

    ---Event2
     ----EventName
     ----IsAccepted
     ----TotalAdults
     ----TotalChildren
```

ng-model for my event fields for e.g. is set as

```
indata.im.EventList[0].IsAccepted, indata.im.EventList[1].IsAccepted and indata.im.EventList[2].IsAccepted
```

**Issue I am facing here is that the JSON emitted  has additional index attached to it. "0" , "1", "2". How to remove this index numbers that are getting added here**

```
   {  
   "Name":"Kunal",
   "EventList":{  
      "0":{  
         "TotalAdults":"3",
         "TotalChildren":"2",
         "IsAccepted":"1",
         "EventName":"Sangeet"
      },
      "1":{  
         "TotalAdults":"1",
         "TotalChildren":"2",
         "IsAccepted":"1",
         "EventName":"Marriage"
      },
      "2":{  
         "TotalAdults":"2",
         "TotalChildren":"1",
         "EventName":"Reception"
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Do you declare `EventList` in the controller? Try to declare it as an array - `indata.im.EventList=[]` not as an object - `indata.im.EventList={}`

Comment: Nope EventList is not declared anywhere in my controller. Let me check that

Comment: in regards to ng-repeat, it doesn't care about fixed vs. variable length. It's just iterating over a given array. You have an array of 3 questions, use the array operator. It will naturally convert the response into the expected structure. `array[1] = "value"` on an object literal is `object: {"1": value}`, which is exactly what your form is building.

Comment: @akn: It worked, that's the solution. Thanks